# Styling only the previous level of a nested unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I wonder if it is possible to style only the previous level of a nested list. To see what I mean, please look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MYasJ/

In the fiddle I could achieve desired effect by overriding the nested list `background-color` property, however this is not what I want -- in my specific circumstances, the parent list has image as a background, the 1st level `li` elements should have red background, but the elements of the nested list should be again transparent so that the background of the "root" list is visible. In the fiddle I use green color instead of picture, but I hope you get the idea.

There are several questions on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787342/nested-list-styling-how-to-separate-styles), but they either cover different topic or the solution involves overriding the children properties -- but this does not solve my case.

EDIT: Little elaboration: the problem is because the nested list is contained within the parent `li` element. This has some good reasons (for example if you float the parent element, the nested list will be floated with it), but also the result that you cannot (at least I do not see how, this is my question) style the `li` element only. I had some luck with `:first-line` pseudo class but this obviously does not work on multiline items nor does it span the whole width of the `li` element.

Comment: No, because the sub-levels are contained within the previous level. So you have to set a `background-color` on the lower-levels to 'mask' that `background-color`

Comment: That's what I do in my fiddle. I set it to transparent, but then, obviously, the background of the containing element is visible. The whole point of this question is how to avoid it.

Comment: You have no choice.  You have to use an extra element in there somewhere.  When you set a transparent background on the child list, you're allowing its parent's background (which is red) to show through.  The parent element would have to be transparent as well for the green to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML code both `"Only this item should have red background"` text node and the nested `<ul>` are children of the parent `<li>`. Thus, they are displayed on red background.

You may want to wrap the text into a `<div>` and assign background color to it.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <div>Only this item should have red background</div>
        <ul>
            <li>But this item should have no background</li>
            <li>Just like this one</li>
            <li>So the green background of the root ul element is visible</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

#nav > li > div {
    background-color: red;
}
```