# Styling nested li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787342/nested-list-styling-how-to-separate-styles) in regards to styling inner `li` elements but what I am concerned about is that something like:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      content
      <ul>
        <li> more content <li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Which could have extremely deep nesting would look bad when styled that is to say if I try and style the outer most `li` sith something like `border: 1px, solid, #333;` that the box will wrap around everything that is nested in that li instead of just "content."

Now you might be thinking "add a inner div to wrap around your content, I am unsure how to do that with something like this:

```
  renderComments: function(comments) {
      // Return undefined if there are no comments to process;
     // alternatively, it /may/ be appropriate to return an empty UL.
     if (!comments || !comments.length) {
         return;
     }

     // Create the container UL for the comments in this level.
     var list = $('<ul>');
     for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) { // Don't use for..in for arrays
         var comment = comments[i];

         // Create an LI for each comment and add it to the container
         var item = $('<li>')
             .attr('id', "comment-" + comment.id);
         // Add the LI to the UL parent
         list.append(item);
         // Add appropriate items to LI for comment
         item.append($('<div>'));
         item.append($('<h1>').text(comment.author));
         item.append($('<p>').text(comment.comment));

         // And then do the same for each child level of comments..
         var childrenList = this.renderComments(comment.children);
         if (childrenList) {
             // ..adding children (UL) container to the current item (LI)
             item.append(childrenList);
         }
     }

     // Return container to be used by caller
     return list;
  },
```

Which actually creates me my nested list that can go on for ever (in theory)

Comment: I'm not getting what your question is. :S

Comment: It looks like you're already doing that: you're appending a `div` to the LI elements. What is the expected behavior, vs. what you're actually seeing?

Comment: @Palpatim The problem is that it does: `<li><div></div> <h1></h1> <p></p></li>`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles See above comment

Comment: `var d = $('<div>'); d.append('<h1>'); d.append('<p>'); item.append(d);` will give you `<li><div><h1></h1> <p></p></div></li>` if that is what you want to style the `div` and all its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're `append`ing to the `li` element sequentially, instead of constructing your comment as a tree and then appending that structure to the `li`. Try something like this:

```
var item = $('<li>').attr('id', "comment-" + comment.id);
var comment = $('<div>');
var author = $('<h1>').text(comment.author);
var commentText = $('<p>').text(comment.comment);

comment.append(author);
comment.append(commentText);
item.append(comment);
list.append(item);
```

This has an added benefit of making your code slightly more readable by naming each DOM node you're creating.

And make sure to review the jQuery docs for [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to see if the other might suit your use case better.